# Segment string into array, regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which looks like this:

```
"[segment1][segment2][segment2]"
```

What I'd like is to be able to split the string into an array, so I'd end up with:

```
Array[0] = "segment1", Array[1] = "segment2", Array[2] = "segment3"
```

I've tried using the string split function, but it doesn't seem to do exactly what I want. I was wondering if anyone has some regex which might help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the slice of the string without the first and last characters, then split on `][`:

```
s = "[segment1][segment2][segment2]"
s[1:-1].split('][')
```

outputs

```
['segment1', 'segment2', 'segment2']
```

Comment: Also, per Tim Pietzcker's answer, you could use `s.strip('[]').split('][')`, using `.strip()` instead of the slice `[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `re.split()` function:

```
subject = "[segment1][segment2][segment2]"
reobj = re.compile("[][]+")
result = reobj.split(subject.strip("[]"))
print result
```

gives you:

```
['segment1', 'segment2', 'segment2']
```

Edit: Added a `.strip()` to avoid an empty first and last element of the resulting list.